# Is it possible to lauch Interactive processes from Java?

Tags: java, process, launch, interaction

Normally, when we launch a process from Java, we lose controll over it, and the java machine simply waits for an answer from said process. I was wondering wether is it possible to lauch a process and and interact with it. Specifically, I require to do this on AS400, but any working method would be usefull (regardless on which OS was it tested on).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible, but will take you quite a bit of multithreaded programming. Google around for "java interact with process". There are a lot of StackOverflow questions covering this.

Comment: Did you look at apache commns exec library.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to interact with a child process.

One of the easiest is to use the input and output streams of the process.

- Use [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) to write to the child process's input stream.
- Use [Process.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) to read from the child process's output stream.